# Firefox splits up Express response readableStream sometimes

Tags: javascript, express, firefox, fetch

I'm trying to stream HTML strings from my Express backend using a series of response.write for the sense of *real-time* updating, since I'm doing some HTTP requests in the middle, then appending them to the DOM. I'm extracting a pseudocode fragment from a given Wiki page as part of my response for context.

Everything is working fine in Chrome however Firefox seems to **sometimes** split the stream into two, obviously then not being able to parse a HTML string as it gets split half way through a tag.

Again, sometimes Firefox takes the larger response as a whole and works fine but most often it splits it.

Is this something to do with Firefox's reading of readableStream's vs Chrome? Or am I missing something in my code?

**Edit:** [How the stream gets split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uCGu.png) (too low rep to imbed)

Stream being sent:

```js
res.write(`<p class="update">&#8594; Fetching page content...</p>`);

//Querying Wiki API here (code not shown)

//returning parsed HTML
parsed_frag = parsed_frag.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');

res.write(`<p class="program">&#8594; Fragment ${frag_num + 1} for ${response.data.parse.displaytitle}:</p>`);
res.write(`<div id="0" class="result">${parsed_frag}</div>`);
res.write(`<p class="program">&#8594; (C = copy to clipboard, N = next fragment, R = restart)</p>`);
res.write(`<div class="program">~/pseudo-fetcher<div id="key-input" class="input key-input" contenteditable="true"></div></div>`);

res.status(200).end();
```

The parsed_frag variable holds the extracted HTML in a string. I want the whole thing to be read as a single part, rather than randomly split when read. Since I'm using res.write beforehand, res.send isn't useful.

Comment: Your server code cannot make ANY assumptions about what chunks data is going to arrive in.  If you're trying to do that, then that's just wrong server code.  You have to read/buffer on the server until some sort of delimiter is encountered and you then know you can process that chunk of data.  That chunk may arrive all at once or may arrive in several different pieces.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you yeah I see the flaw in what I was doing